# How to feed contents of a "shebang" file into the program it invokes?

Tags: c++, c, unix, shebang

I want my program `foo` to take input from a shebang file. This file consists of the shebang line followed by some text:

```
#!/usr/bin/env foo
food_for_foo
more_food_for_foo
```

I want `foo` to read this text (ignoring the first line), and then go interactive.

I thought that `foo` would get the contents of the file on `stdin`, so I wrote it to read from that. But when I execute the above shebang file, `foo` starts, and goes interactive immediately, ignoring all input from the shebang file.

What is the proper way to get the script contents?

Comment: to start with, show us `foo()`.

Comment: After reformulation of the question it should be clear that it is not about coding details of `foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get the contents of the script via `stdin`. Instead, the path of the script is passed to your program as an argument. You need to use that argument to open the file and read the script.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    std::ifstream script(argv[1]);
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(script, line)) {
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

should output the script contents line by line. You'd want to ignore the first line (perhaps generalising that to any line beginning with `#` to allow comments in the script) and do whatever you do with the remaining lines.

Comment: @user3159253: What do you mean?

Comment: The first line of the input data should be checked for shebang and skipped, if it is

Comment: @user3159253: Yes, you'd probably want to do that if you're interpreting the script and not just giving a simple example of how to read it.

Answer (score 3):

The path to the script with shebang is passed as a command parameter to the `foo`. So `foo` should check its args and process them accordingly (supposedly ignoring the first line if it's a shebang.)

Here's a small python script to demonstrate things (I'm too lazy to implemented it as a C/C++ program, check @MikeSeymour's example for that):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print("processing startup data from %s" % sys.argv[1])
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as startup:
        first = startup.readline()
        if not first.startswith("#!"):
            print("startup input data '%s'" % first)
        for l in startup.readlines():
            print("startup input data '%s'" % l)
print("performing regular operations...")
for l in sys.stdin.readlines():
     print("handling regular interactive input line '%s'" % l)
```

or something like this :)

Input script may contain the first shebang line, or may not.